# MATCH function does not work

Tags: google-sheets

MATCH function does not appear to work at all. Given the following data:

`$7,109.19 | $867.19 | -$5,374.81 | -$11,616.81`

```
=MATCH(MAX(FILTER(B122:U122, B122:U122 < 0)),B122:U122)
```

returns the error:

> error: Did not find value -5374.810000000005

How can it not match a field for a value generated purely out of values that exist in the array?

All I really want to do is select a cell in a different row of the same column of the value that *should* be returned by that match call.

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you find my other answer to your previous question helpful? If yes, then please mark as such.

Comment: Was my answer of use?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the third parameter, of the `MATCH` formula, explicitly:

### Formula

```
=MATCH(MAX(FILTER(B122:U122, B122:U122<0)),B122:U122, 0)
```

### Explained

The third parameter of the `MATCH` will tell it to find an exact match, as stated in the help:

> 0 indicates exact match, and is required in situations where range is
>   not sorted.

By default it is set at 1, if no value is given. This will yield a completely different result.

### Reference

- [MATCH - Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093378)
- [Detailed explanation](http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/use-match-function-excel-find-position-value-list)

Comment: Ah, you are right about the `FILTER` mistake. Unfortunately, that was only an error in the question not my actual use. The `MAX` portion is working correctly and returning the `-$5,374.81` value. What I am unclear about is why the `MATCH` call is failing to match that value (especially since it is pulled directly from the range I am matching against). I understand how the 3rd parameter is supposed to work, but it does not appear to actually work (with any of the possible values).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but for an exact match (case sensitive) it seems setting the match parameter to 0 is broken. See the attached picture and linked spreadsheet:

https://i.imgur.com/bfVFZeo.png

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kbrdmsIRugwcBhiGM5FUd63Maq6hzkNEYvMrx7uqSCA/edit?usp=sharing